# Convert C# DateTime to JavaScript date automatically using Json Serialization in Dot Net Core 2 WebApi

Tags: javascript, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

Is it possible to convert C# DateTime fields to JavaScript dates automatically when returning results from a Dot Net Core 2.0 WebApi Controller call?

At the moment, when a DateTime value is returned from a server side call, it returns in the format: "2013-02-01T00:00:00"

I would have thought that it would be possible to set the JsonSerializer options to return the value already converted into a JavaScript date without needing to parse it via a secondary parser such as moment.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at using `JSON.parse()`'s optional "reviver" parameter?

Comment: Your question isn't clear because you say that you are returning results *from* WebAPI, but you aren't saying what you're doing with those results on the client side - which is entirely the point of your question.  In other words, it doesn't matter what platform generated the string - it might as well be Ruby or Python.  How you interpret it client-side is only a client-side problem.

Comment: Well, if I used it in a client-side data grid, for example, then I'd want it to be sortable as a date. The best way to do this is to use a JavaScript date object to represent the date.

Answer (score -1):

you should add this following line to your startup.cs class in ConfigureService function:

```
services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat);
```

Then you can get date in json format while serialize data.

Comment: Noooo..  don't do that! That format should die a horrible death. :)  https://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Comment: then you should get data from database as a string format which you needed.
for example if you want to get date in 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss' then you should return date like date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss").

Comment: Only if you're going to display it directly to a user, and you're taking their culture information into account.  Otherwise, stick to standard ISO 8601 format that is now the default.  The OP is asking for a `Date` object in JavaScript, not a user presentable localized string.  Ultimately only a string can be returned from an API.  Anything else requires *parsing*.

Comment: It is a standard string format. I don't believe that just because the API returns strings that it means that we can't use a serializer at the boundary to convert it to a JavaScript date object. It gets done the other way around when we submit a date to the Web API controller. I really want it to be automatic and avoid having to map every returned array's date fields in javascript, for which I currently use "moment".

Comment: I should add that I am currently using Angular 4. The data is currently returned and I call json() on the data to convert it to an in-memory json object. (Of course, that said, the current http service is on the way out - to be replaced by HttpClient service, found here: https://angular.io/guide/http ).